# How would I go about removing duplicate draws from this card drawing program?

Tags: python

```
#Imports random method
import random

#Gets the value of the card
def getCard():
    global cards,cardSelect
    #List of possible cards in an array
    cards = ["Ace",2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"Jack","Queen","King"]
    #Selects a card
    cardSelect = random.choice(cards)

#Gets the suit of the card 
def getSuit():
    global suits,suitSelect
    #List of possible suits in an array
    suits = ["Hearts","Spades","Clubs","Diamonds"]
        #Selects a suit
    suitSelect = random.choice(suits)

#Prints the cards
def buildCard():
    global cards,suits,cardSelect,suitSelect

    #Calls other functions
    getCard()
    getSuit()

    #Chooses color randomly
    color = random.randint(1,2)
    #Defines randomly selected value to the name of a color : Red or Black
    if color == 1:
        color = "Red"
    if color == 2:
        color = "Black"

    #Prints every card in a 52 deck
    print("You drew a",color,cardSelect,"of",suitSelect)

#Calls BuildCard
while True:
    input()
    buildCard()
```

Essentially what I need this program to do is print a randomly generated card (as it does now) but keep score of what card has been generated to prevent duplicate card draws in the program. I was thinking there might be a way to do it using a set() or maybe remove() or pop()? Not sure because I'm still new to Python. Thanks!

Comment: Coming from scratch? Please stop immediately using global variables for return values, i.e. replace `cardSelect = random.choice(cards)` with `return random.choice(cards)`. You can have `suits` and `cards` global, if you want, but then define them before the first function.

Comment: You can avoid issues later if you make your lists of a consistent type.  Your `cards` list is perfectly valid, but experience has shown me that a single type in an array makes the code easier to maintain.  Of course, not a problem in this exercise, but a general rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building your deck first (non-randomly) and then shuffling the deck.

```
import random
cards = ["Ace",2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"Jack","Queen","King"]
suits = ["Hearts","Spades","Clubs","Diamonds"]

deck=[]
for card in cards:
  for suit in suits:
    deck.append( ( card, suit ))

random.shuffle(deck)
for n,card in enumerate(deck):
  print(n,card)
```

It should be noted that I left out the colors of the cards completely.  After all, color is not random but rather just a function of the suit.  And so, if you want to include the color information in your cards as well, you have a number of options:

1. You can include the color in the suit name
2. You can provide a dict to map suits to colors.
3. You can provide the information in the suit names as a tuple.

Options 1 and 3 can be implemented with a change to a line of code:

#### Option 1:

Include color with suit name:

```
suits = ["Red Hearts","Black Spades","Black Clubs","Red Diamonds"]
```

#### Option 3:

Include color as a tuple:

```
import random
cards = ["Ace",2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"Jack","Queen","King"]
suits = [("Hearts","Red"),("Spades","Black"),("Clubs","Black"),("Diamonds","Red")]

deck=[]
for card in cards:
  for suit in suits:
    deck.append( ( card, suit ))

random.shuffle(deck)
for n,card in enumerate(deck):
  print(n,card)
```

Example output from Option 3 above:

```
0 (9, ('Spades', 'Black'))
1 (8, ('Spades', 'Black'))
2 (4, ('Diamonds', 'Red'))
3 (10, ('Spades', 'Black'))
...
```